# SDL undeclared filename and apply_surface not working

Tags: c++, sdl, filenames, apply, surface

I've recently dived into some SDL tutorials, but am having difficulty compiling this one in particular using DevC++ with the SDL library:
http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson05/index.php

I am getting this particular error: `filename' undeclared (first use this function) and it points to the filename.c_str() ); area of the code, as well as a few others listed in the compile log. I'd like to also investigate the "apply_surface" not being recognized as well. I have included the following headers:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "SDL/SDL.h"
#include "quickcg.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_mixer.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL/SDL_ttf.h"

using namespace QuickCG;
```

Linker options include suggestions based on other threads I've found with the same issue, it appears I'm not alone but I haven't quite found the solution that applies to my code yet:

```
-lmingw32
-mwindows
-lSDLmain
-lSDL
-lSDL_mixer
-lSDL_image
-lSDL_ttf
-lstdc++
```

CODE SNIPPET:

```
int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])
{
    {
    SDL_Surface* title = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* hud = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* screen = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* loadedImage = NULL;
    SDL_Surface* optimizedImage = NULL;

    loadedImage = IMG_Load( filename.c_str() );

    if (loadedImage != NULL)
    {
        optimizedImage = SDL_DisplayFormat( loadedImage );
        SDL_FreeSurface( loadedImage );
        if( optimizedImage != NULL)
```

etc etc

COMPILE LOG:

```
Compiler: Default compiler
Building Makefile: "D:\Coding\Raycaster\Makefile.win"
Executing  make...
make.exe -f "D:\Coding\Raycaster\Makefile.win" all
g++.exe -c raycaster.cpp -o raycaster.o -I"D:/Coding/Dev-Cpp/lib/gcc/mingw32/3.4.2    
/include"  -I"D:/Coding/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2/backward"  -I"D:/Coding/Dev-Cpp
/include/c++/3.4.2/mingw32"  -I"D:/Coding/Dev-Cpp/include/c++/3.4.2"  -I"D:/Coding
/Dev-Cpp/include"    -fexpensive-optimizations -O3 -mwindows

raycaster.cpp: In function `int SDL_main(int, char**)':
raycaster.cpp:117: error: `filename' undeclared (first use this function)
raycaster.cpp:117: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for
each function it appears in.)

raycaster.cpp:130: error: invalid conversion from `SDL_Surface*' to `int'
raycaster.cpp:133: error: `apply_surface' undeclared (first use this function)
raycaster.cpp:134: error: `hud' undeclared (first use this function)

make.exe: *** [raycaster.o] Error 1

Execution terminated
```

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm yet another dumbo newbie to the whole C++ scene, but this is more of a learning experiment than anything else; I'd just love to build a basic raycaster and am stuck getting the hud to display.

Comment: Am I getting it right - you've modified "lesson" (for some unknown reason), making a lot of mistakes in process, and now wondering why it isn't compiling? How about just downloading source (link at bottom of article you referring to) and not breaking it?

Comment: The source code version doesn't run for me anyway; but either way, I have managed to fix the problem. I think I've jumped in too far ahead and am going to go a bit further back; so far I've had people relay inconsistent starting points for someone to learn C++ in, with someone suggesting an enormous 1008 page book, and a forum member advising I start off by "coding a raycaster" which is what this was to be a the title-screen area of, but I'm finding that with only 2 days of experience, this sort of coding level is appearing a bit too indepth for me.

Thankyou for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First: why did you comment out parts of the main function `int main(int /*argc*/, char */*argv*/[])`??? it should look like this: `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`

Second: unless you have declared the `filename`variable in the global scope before main (which the error suggests that you haven't) you need to declare it and provide a value for it. Since you're using the `.c_str()`method on it `filename`should probably be a `str::string`. Try adding this before the IMG_Load line:

```
std::string filename = "path to your file here";
```

If you want to know what is wrong with the rest of the code you have to post it too.

Comment: Actually, the code was already commented out (it came as part of a tutorial). Nonetheless, I've managed to fix the issue, thankyou for your advice.